# Creating exact new binary file from old binary with different extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script and I need to change file extension and create a new file  like `paris.png` from `paris.jpg` and keep the old file `paris.jpg`.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path("paris.jpg")
filename_replace_ext = filename.with_suffix('.png')
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    f.write(filename_replace_ext)
#print(filename_replace_ext)
```

Comment: Can you please fix your question and make it more readable?

Comment: You could use [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to make an exact copy of the file ***and*** rename it all in a single  function call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best solution is to copy the original image and then change the extension of the new file:

```
from shutil import copyfile
import os

copyfile("Desert.jpg", "Desert_new.jpg")

thisFile = "Desert_new.jpg"
base = os.path.splitext(thisFile)[0]
os.rename(thisFile, base + ".png")
```

Comment: `copyfile` allow the full name of the destination to be specified, so there there's no need to manually rename it if you use it properly…

Comment: And assuming the use of `pathlib` as OP it's even easier: `copyfile(filename, filename.with_suffix('.png'))`

Comment: Tanks martineau and Tomerikoo  for your help